# google spreadsheet query function: Extrange behavoir with columns with different types of cells

Tags: function, google-sheets

I use the new google spreadsheet and I detect an extrange behavior when a column has different types (number and string) and has automatic format option. Some cells disappear from the result.

```
Ej.:

11  z
22  z
11  z
xx  z
yy  z

Result of =query(A1:B5;"select *"):
11  z
22  z
11  z
    z
    z

Result of =query(A1:B5;"select A, count(B) group by A"):
    count 
    2
11  2
22  1
```

It's clear that when the column has a string format, it works.
But sometimes, when I use results of the forms to summarise data, the new entry doesn't respect the column format (as previous spreadsheet version it does), so the spreedsheet try to convert to a number the form entry if it is possible. Thus, I have a string and number data in the same column.

Does anyone know how to make the 'query' function to work properly, regardless of the data type of the cell in a column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AD:AM](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/jitrLolaziU) May 10, 2012:

> Unfortunately it's just a limitation with QUERY, Marinus, that it will only "accept" one data type per field.